# send folder via ssh then compress and send it back

Tags: ssh, compression, tar, 7-zip

I need to send folder with eml files from "A" to "B", then compress them with 7z and send back to "A"
what i have is

```
ssh user@server "tar -cf - .folder" | 7z a -si compressed_folder.7z
```

but it makes tar.7z, so i need to decompress tar before creating 7z archive
How to achieve that?

ps. I cant compress them on "A" because of little ram and cpu

Comment: There are many ways around this, but they require a less clean command. Tar is packaging the files together to transmit them as a single unit. You could do away with tar and usecscp to a temporary directory (which you then need to clean up) or untar the files once they are on the remote before 7zipping them (again more lines of vide, cleanup etc)

Comment: Is 7z a hard requirement?  gzip or bzip2 seems like it would make way more sense here.

Comment: @Bolwerk unfortunately it must be 7z, but i got your idea :)

Comment: Only asking out of curiosity: why? Also, why can't 7z be installed on the remote host?

Comment: 7z is installed on remote host by default, but it is a synology NAS with low performance cpu, and creating a 7z archive took me 40minutes, and on different host it takes about 2 minutes ;D, that's why i'm doing it on different one. I'm compressing thousands of eml files, which are very very simmilar, and 7z with lzma is best for it, also it will be easier later for c# program to decompress a month and show specific eml to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I promise you it's ugly, but I tested and it works on my Linux box.

Assumptions: you want to backup only one folder (this won't be easily adapted to multiple folders) and you trust you aren't overwriting anything on the client side. The folder is in the home directory of the remote server. You probably want to set up passwordless authentication for ssh, or else you're going to have to type a password twice.

Warnings: there may be OS-specific quirks in how this is done. For instance, if you crontab things you might want to make your paths more specific.  Maybe you're on a BSD, so you might not have `bash` by default. I use the date command to create a unique filename to upload back to the server, but that might work differently in different hosts. There is also no error checking in this, though that's easy to add in a script.

I created a few variables to simplify things.  The $cssh variable keeps me from having to repeat the ssh connection string. Note that I changed your folder name to test/, but since it's only used once I didn't put it in a variable.

I'm wrapping it all in `bash` or `sh` (usually they're pretty interchangeable on Linux) to make suppressing output easy, but if you don't care about suppressing output you can remove that and make it somewhat less long.

```
bash -c 'file=bu$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%Hh\%Mm\%Ss_\%A).7z; cssh="user@host"; folder=`ssh $cssh "tar -cf - test/ | gzip -9c" | gzip -d | tar -xvf - | head -n 1`; 7z a $file $folder && scp $file $cssh:~ && rm $file && rm -r $folder' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If using `ssh` is a hard requirement, and you want no `scp` you can use `dd` to copy the file over ssh:

```
sh -c 'file=bu$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%Hh\%Mm\%Ss_\%A).7z; cssh="user@host"; folder=`ssh $cssh "tar -cf - test/ | gzip -9c" | gzip -d | tar -xvf - | head -n 1`; 7z a $file $folder && dd if=$file | ssh $cssh "dd of=$file" && rm $file && rm -r $folder' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I gzip'd the archive before streaming it to the local host because that can save a lot of bandwidth with plaintext files.  You can remove the pipe to `gzip -9c`, but if you do you need to remove the corresponding decompression on the localhost `gzip -d`

Or to put the first command into a script to make it clearer:

```
#!/bin/sh

# make a unique file name to temporarily use for storing 7z'd folder
# will look something like bu2019-09-29-00h18m49s_Sunday.7z
file=bu$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%Hh\%Mm\%Ss_\%A).7z; 

# SSH connection strong
cssh="user@host"; 

# downloads the remote folder and gets the name of the folder in one variable
folder=`ssh $cssh "tar -cf - test/ | gzip -9c" | gzip -d | tar -xvf - | head -n 1`;

# compress, upload, remove folder, remove file
7z a $file $folder && scp $file $cssh:~ && rm $file && rm -r $folder
```

Comment: meanwhile i came into somethin' almost identical, and again i do not use gzip because of cpu ;/

```tar -cf - 2019-09-*eml | ssh user@host "cd ~/archiwa; tar -xf -"
ssh user@host "cd ~/archiwa;7z a -m0=lzma -mx=5 -md=64m -ms=on 2019-09.7z 2019-09-*eml"
scp user@host:~/archiwa/2019-09.7z ./```